# R - Change Data Structure on the Import/Read In

Tags: r, data-structures, trim

I am new to R and trying find the "quickest" code to change column structure on the data read in. I am familiar with "colclasses" and as. but am wondering if I can use colclasses like as.

With colclasses, i know you can set the structure of each column and then "read them in" when you upload like i have done with "na.strings." With as. i am only able to change the structure of the column after is has been uploaded and recognizes the column name.

Below is my current code, and again, i would like to be able to change the column structure on the upload like i am with na.strings:

```
#setup "NA" values
na.strings<-c("","NA")

#import data
df<-read.csv("DataLossDB.csv",
             na.strings = na.strings,
             row.names = 13)

#change structure
df$Date<-as.character(df$Date)
df$Organization<-as.character(df$Organization)
df$RecordType<-as.character(df$RecordType)
df$Story<-as.character(df$Story)
```

Comment: Set the option `stringsAsFactors=F` in `read.csv`

Comment: you can also use the as.is=TRUE argument.

Answer (score 0):

I use the package `reshape2` to do major reorganization of columns.

Also, I use the option `as.is=TRUE`

The datalossdb data (i.e., http://datalossdb.org/exports/dataloss.csv) is not available anyplace I have searched.  If that `DataLossDB.csv` file you are loading is one and the same, perhaps you could share it someplace.

You can find data I have made available here: http://www.knosof.co.uk/ESEUR/